# how to get the scope of a JAVA bean?

Tags: java, class, jsf, get, scope

we of course know the scope of our beans, but for batch processing is it possible to get the scope of a java bean ?

and is it different in JSF 1 and JSF 2 ?

thanks

Comment: You forgot to tell which JSF version exactly you're using and are interested in, and how exactly and in what format exactly you got a hand of the "java bean" in question (show code for that to avoid ambiguity caused by starter's terminology mistakes!). Edit and fix the question accordingly. It's otherwise a way too broad question.

Comment: thanks for the response. i currently am using jsf1.2 and i am interested in both jsf1x and jsf 2x.

Comment: JSF 1.x and 2.x are a world of difference. An answer for JSF 2.x with `@ManagedBean` would not be suitable in any way for JSF 1.x. Moreover, your current "answer" is not JSF 1.x specific, but Woodstock specific. Yet you omitted this important detail from the question. A JSF 1.x approach would in turn likely not work for Woodstock. And, with Woodstock you've actually a much bigger problem ...

Comment: thanks. my answer is metaphorical, just to solve my current problem and for those who may need a similar solution. on the other hand, is there a chance that you can explain why woodstock is a bigger problem ? MfG

Comment: It's dead since almost a decade. And it has many design problems.

Answer (score 0):

this may help :

```
  public static String scope_bul(Object x_obj) {
     String       w_scope = "";

    try {
      //     if ( x_obj.getClass().isInstance(Class.forName("com.sun.rave.web.ui.appbase.AbstractApplicationBean")) ) {
             if ( x_obj            instanceof                com.sun.rave.web.ui.appbase.AbstractApplicationBean    ) {
                  w_scope = "A";
        }
      //else if ( x_obj.getClass().isInstance(Class.forName("com.sun.rave.web.ui.appbase.AbstractSessionBean"    )) ) {
        else if ( x_obj            instanceof                com.sun.rave.web.ui.appbase.AbstractSessionBean        ) {
                  w_scope = "S";
        }
      //else if ( x_obj.getClass().isInstance(Class.forName("com.sun.rave.web.ui.appbase.AbstractViewBean"       )) ) { //JSF 2
      //else if ( x_obj            instanceof                com.sun.rave.web.ui.appbase.AbstractViewBean"          ) { //JSF 2
      //          w_scope = "V";                                                                                        //JSF 2
      //}                                                                                                               //JSF 2
      //else if ( x_obj.getClass().isInstance(Class.forName("com.sun.rave.web.ui.appbase.AbstractPageBean"       )) ||
        else if ( x_obj            instanceof                 com.sun.rave.web.ui.appbase.AbstractPageBean           ||
      //          x_obj.getClass().isInstance(Class.forName("com.sun.rave.web.ui.appbase.AbstractRequestBean"    )) ) {
                  x_obj            instanceof                 com.sun.rave.web.ui.appbase.AbstractRequestBean        ) {
                  w_scope = "R";
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("> ERROR (el) : " + e.getMessage());
    }

    return        w_scope;
```

}